# Trouble recognising external monitor

Tags: monitor, external-monitor, vga

I'm a first time Ubuntu user (using Ocelot) and know very little about computers. My laptop screen is broken and I'm trying to connect to an external monitor through a VGA cable but I can't get the system to recognise the new monitor. I've tried using different drivers and settings in NVIDIA, the function key, as well as entering xrandr --output VGA1 --auto into the terminal. It just says output VGA not found but it recognises there's a monitor in NVIDIA. I know it is possible to do since my friend who put this OS on my computer did it last night, but we can't do it again after restarting the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Open up Nvidia settings tool. Then go to "X Server Display Configuration". There you should see your monitor. 
[image: X Server Display Configuration]

Click on the monitor you like change. 
Then click on "Configuration:" And choose your setting "Twin view" or "Separate X screen" the later one requires that you log out and in again.

[image: Choosing configuration]
Just for test, choose "Twin View" and click apply. Now you should have the screen activated to the right of your other screen.

If this works, then you could make the changes permanent. And if you like to only use that monitor then you should try the "Separate X screen" configuration.

Close down Nvidia settings tool. And then reopen it with root. You can do this from the terminal by typing *sudo nvidia-settings* in the terminal. 
This will open the nvidia settings dialog again but with root privileges so you can save the changes and make them permanent for every boot.

Now you choose  "Separate X screen" from the configuration and then you click "Save to X Configuration File" at the bottom of the window. And follow the steps.

Then log out and back in again and you should have the screen working.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I tried this it told me that it couldn't apply the attributes and nothing happened.